# Как лучше реализовать конструкторы в структуре больших чисел?

Tags: c++, biginteger, длинная-арифметика

Пишу структуру больших чисел. Остановился на написании конструкторов.

Вот пример как я их реализовал:

```
#include "big_uint.h"

big_uint::big_uint(){
    size = 0;
    buff_size = 4;
    bits = new uint32_t[buff_size];
}

big_uint::big_uint(uint64_t value) : big_uint() {
    bits[0] = (uint32_t)value;
    bits[1] = (uint32_t)(value >> 32);
    size += (bool)bits[1] + 1;
}
big_uint::big_uint(uint32_t value) : big_uint() {
    size = 1;
    bits[0] = value;
}
big_uint::big_uint(uint16_t value) : big_uint((uint32_t)value) {}

big_uint::big_uint(int64_t value) : big_uint((uint64_t)value) {}
big_uint::big_uint(int32_t value) : big_uint((uint32_t)value) {}
big_uint::big_uint(int16_t value) : big_uint((uint32_t)value) {}

big_uint::big_uint(const uint32_t* const bits, uint32_t size){
    this->size = size;
    this->buff_size = size + 4;
    this->bits = new uint32_t[this->buff_size];
    const uint32_t *s = bits;
    for(uint32_t* f = this->bits; s < bits + size; *f = *s, ++f, ++s);
}

big_uint::big_uint(const big_uint& other) : big_uint(other.bits, other.size) {}

big_uint::big_uint(big_uint&& other) {
    this->size = other.size;
    this->buff_size = other.buff_size;
    this->bits = other.bits;
    other.bits = nullptr;
}
```

И вопрос в том, как их реализовать лучше как у меня или каждый конструктор по своему? То есть в конструкторе `uint32_t` писать `size = 1; bits[0] = value;`, и такой же код в `uint16_t`.

Мне показалось, что это лучше чем писать в каждом конструкторе практически один и тот же код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хотите супер контроля над своим кодом - пишите каждый конкретный конструктор так как нужно. Похоже это правильный способ в Вашем случае - конструкторы будут немного отличатся.

Но если Вы считаете, что у Вас содержимое их похожее/одинаковое - используйте делегирующий конструктор. Собственно Вы это и сделали. Правда я не уверен, что там все правильно - типы разные в констукторах и есть сразу несколько конструкторов с одинаковой сигнатурой.

Посмотрим, что ещё можно сделать.

В некоторых случаях можно написать макрос, который просто размножить

```
#define ctor(type) big_uint::big_uint(type value) : big_uint((uint64_t)value) {}
// потом где то так
ctor(uint32)
ctor(uint16)
```

Но сейчас макросы не в почете. Сейчас модно шаблоны:) Сделаем на шаблонах.

```
class big_int {
public:
template<typename T>
big_int(T value) { m_value = value;}

private:
  uint64_t m_value;

};
```

и теперь можно вот так

```
big_int a{1u};
big_int b{100};
big_int c{100lu};
```

Правда конструктор по умолчанию теперь не будет автоматом генерироваться. Так что его придется дописать явно. Также не забывайте, что определив конструкторы копирования/перемещения, неплохо написать и операторы копирования/перемещения (правило трех/пяти)

Посмотрел на конструктор перемещения. Рекомендуется в них объект-донор оставить "пустым", то есть, не забыть занулить переменные. Где то так

```
big_uint::big_uint(big_uint&& other) {
    this->size = other.size;
    this->buff_size = other.buff_size;
    this->bits = other.bits;
    other.bits = nullptr;
    other.size = 0;
    other.buff_size = 0;
}
```

зачем? после перемещения объект должен быть готов к удалению. Я не знаю, как именно устроен деструктор, но с занулением будет надежнее.

И не забывайте, что перед таким конструктром неплохо написать explicit, что бы случайно не написать `big_int a = 2;`, хотя может оно и подходит в данном случае.

Comment: А что если создать функцию `inline` и из каждого конструктора вызывать её?

Comment: можно создать функцию и вызывать ее для каждого конструктора. Но только зачем inline? оптимизация?

Comment: ну вроде да, как будто я написал код в каждом конструкторе, но нет вызвал только 1 функцию. Если я не ошибаюсь `inline` на этапе компилирования, подставит содержимое функции на место её вызова. У меня как раз функция не такая большая будет.

Comment: компиляторы сейчас достаточно умные, что бы это все сделать самостоятельно. более того, многие компиляторы сейчас игнорируют inline

Comment: Ну тогда наверно нет смысла inline писать. А вот такой маленький вопрос появился,  а сколько занимает вызов функции? Например как лучше написать функцию, которую вы предложили комментарий назад, как функция с аргументов value по значение или по ссылке? Разница большая будет?

Comment: так как Вы будете туда передавать число, которое будет 2-4 байта (ок, 8 в самом худшем случае), а ссылка для компилятора это обычно указатель (хотя это очень грубо), который занимает 4 или 8 байт, то разницы никакой. В этом случае я передавал бы просто по значению. Но мне кажется, что Вы хотите на каждом шаге сделать оптимизацию. Не нужно этого делать, пока код не допишите и не сделаете профилирование. А там будет видно